# Search through XML and grab another Node

Tags: c#, xml, search

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Message>
      <MessageID>1</MessageID>
      <Product>
         <SKU>33333-01</SKU>
      </Product>
   </Message>
</Envelope>
```

I've tried googling but whether I'm just not providing the correct search criteria I don't know.

I want to be able to search the XML file based on the MessageID and then grab the SKU.

I then want to search another XML file based on the SKU and remove that message completely.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Message>
      <MessageID>1</MessageID>
      <Inventory>
         <SKU>33333-01</SKU>
         <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </Inventory>
   </Message>   
   <Message>
      <MessageID>2</MessageID>
      <Inventory>
         <SKU>22222-01</SKU>
         <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </Inventory>
   </Message>
</Envelope>
```

Meaning the XML above becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Message>
      <MessageID>2</MessageID>
      <Inventory>
         <SKU>22222-01</SKU>
         <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      </Inventory>
   </Message>
</Envelope>
```

To confirm I cannot confirm that the MessageID will be the same over different XML files.

Thanks in advance for any help.

My questions:

1. How do I search through XML files?
2. How do I then grab another Nodes details
3. Can I remove a complete  from an XML file based on a search?

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `XmlDocument` to load your XML document. Then, you can use XPath for searching any nodes.

   ```
   XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
   document.Load("C:\fileOnTheDisk.xml");
   // or
   document.LoadXml("<a>someXmlString</a>");

   // Returns single element or null if not found    
   var singleNode = document.SelectSingleNode("Envelope/Message[MessageID = '1']"); 

   // Returns a NodeList
   var nodesList = document.SelectNodes("Envelope/Message[MessageID = '1']");
   ```

[Read more about XPath at w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).
Here is a good [XPath Tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath).

2. For example, you can use the following XPath to find nodes in your document by ID:

   ```
   XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
   document.Load("C:\doc.xml");

   var node = document.SelectSingleNode("Envelope/Message[MessageID = '1']");

   var sku = node.SelectSingleNode("Inventory/SKU").InnerText;

   Console.WriteLine("{0} node has SKU = {1}", 1, sku);
   ```

Or you can output all SKUs:

```
    foreach (XmlNode node in document.SelectNodes("Envelope/Message"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} node has SKU = {1}", 
            node.SelectSingleNode("MessageID").InnerText, 
            node.SelectSingleNode("Inventory/SKU").InnerText);
    }
```

It will produce:

```
    1 node has SKU = 33333-01
    2 node has SKU = 22222-01
```

Note that there are possible `NullReferenceException`s if nodes are not present.

3. You can simply remove it using `RemoveChild()` method of its parent.

   ```
   XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
   document.Load("C:\doc.xml");

   var node = document.SelectSingleNode("Envelope/Message[MessageID = '1']");
   node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);

   document.Save("C:\docNew.xml"); // will be without Message 1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to do this:

```
    var doc= XDocument.Load("input.xml");//path of your xml file in which you want to search based on message id.
    var searchNode= doc.Descendants("MessageID").FirstOrDefault(d => d.Value == "1");// It will search message node where its value is 1 and get first of it
     if(searchNode!=null)
     {
        var SKU=searchNode.Parent.Descendants("SKU").FirstOrDefault();
        if(SKU!=null)
        {
           var searchDoc=XDocument.Load("search.xml");//path of xml file where you want to search based on SKU value.
           var nodes =searchDoc.Descendants("SKU").Where(d=>d.Value==SKU.Value).Select(d=>d.Parent.Parent).ToList();
           nodes.ForEach(node=>node.Remove());
           searchDoc.Save("output.xml");//path of output file
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you did this using LINQ to XML - it's much nicer to work with than the old `XmlDocument` API.

For all the examples, you can parse your XML string `xml` to an `XDocument` like so:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

*1. How do I search through XML files?*

You can get the SKU for a specific message ID by querying your document:

```
var sku = (string)doc.Descendants("Message")
    .Where(e => (int)e.Element("MessageID") == 1)
    .SelectMany(e => e.Descendants("SKU"))
    .Single();
```

*2. How do I then grab another Nodes details?*

You can get the `Message` element with a specified SKU using a another query:

```
var message = doc.Descendants("SKU")
    .Where(sku => (string)sku == "33333-01")
    .SelectMany(e => e.Ancestors("Message"))
    .Single();
```

*3. Can I remove a complete element from an XML file based on a search?*

Using your result from step 2, you can simple call `Remove`:

```
message.Remove();
```

Alternatively, you can combine the query from step 2 and simply execute a command to remove any messages that have a specific SKU:

```
doc.Descendants("SKU")
    .Where(sku => (string)sku == "33333-01")
    .SelectMany(e => e.Ancestors("Message"))
    .Remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to answer all your questions:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load("xml1.xml");
XDocument xdoc2 = XDocument.Load("xml2.xml");
string sku = String.Empty;
string searchedID = "2";

//1.searching through an xml file based on path
foreach (XElement message in xdoc1.XPathSelectElements("Envelope/Message"))
{
    if (message.Element("MessageID").Value.Equals(searchedID))
    {
        //2.grabbing another node's details
        sku = message.XPathSelectElement("Inventory/SKU").Value;
    }
}
foreach (XElement message in xdoc2.XPathSelectElements("Envelope/Message"))
{
    if (message.XPathSelectElement("Inventory/SKU") != null && message.XPathSelectElement("Inventory/SKU").Value.Equals(sku))
    {
        //removing a node
        message.Remove();
    }
}
xdoc2.Save("xml2_del.xml");
}
```